# Opening'set location' box of geopoint within repeats in Survey123?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

In my survey, each page contains a repeat for a set of questions and geopoint. The geopoint set location box is open for the repeat on the first page, but it is closed for the rest of the pages. Is there a way I could make sure all the set location boxes are automatically open instead of having to click on them?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this by setting all geopoint function as a required question to answer!